# Autotools - static resources

Tags: linux, unix, configuration, autotools, directory-structure

I am looking for a best practice of using configuration files and static resources.

Many programs use a directory like `/usr/share/myprogram/` for some static files like default configfiles (see `/usr/share/nano/` for example).

Can I configure autotools to use that directory structure for my program as well? Would autotools generate me a preprocessor variable in `config.h` with something like a `resourcepath`?

Comment: are you looking for the _DATA macros?

Comment: Sounds promising. I will research for that keyword! Thank you